# Why can't I select the type of segue in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I connect one view controller to a second view controller, xcode automatically assigns the segue to "push." The menu of different segue types displays for about a second and then disappears and automatically assigns "push" instead of allowing me to manually choose which type of segue I want. Why is this happening? To change it to "modal" for example, xcode is now forcing me to go into the attributes inspector and select it from there rather than allowing me to select it from the popup right when the connection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you got a view_A which embed in the `Navigation Controller` and a View_B which is connected with View_A through `Push_Segue`, it just worked fine. But! But if you want use `Segue` for `Modal` or `Popover` to move to the View_B, you have to create another Navigation controller for the view_B.  Because thats how Modal and Popover work!  Like this:
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for that nice answer; however, that's not my question. I know how to create the segue. My question is why is xcode automatically assigning the type of connection for me? I used to get a popup where I could select it myself. However, xcode now selects the connection type automatically after I make it.

Answer (score 0):

### To change your segue :

- On storyboard click on it (the wire)
- then on left menu :

  - you have choice of making it modal and transition desired.

### method 2, still in storyboard

- tap on destination view controller
- got to `inspector menu`

  - `_presenting segue_`
  - wire to your source controller from desired segue (for modal : take `present modally`, since `modal` is deprecated)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Thanks again, but I know how to do this manually. That's not my question.